# I am sorry, I got this code from my programmer and What does this code do?

Tags: javascript

```
function w_3_wid(str, wid03) {
   var word = new Array();
   var i;
   var ret = '';
   word = str.split(" ");
   for (i = 0; i < word.length; i ++ ) {
      if (word[i].length > wid03 && word[i].search(/&\w+;/) < 0) ret += word[i].substr(0, wid03) + ' ' + word[i].substr(wid03) + ' ';
      else ret += word[i] + ' ';
   }
   return ret;
}
function w_4_wid(str, wid03) {
   if (str.length <= wid03) return str;
   var word = new Array();
   word = str.split(" ");
   var ret = word[0] + ' ';
   var test;
   for (i = 1; i < word.length; i ++ ) {
      test = ret + word[i];
      if (test.length > wid03) return ret + '...';
      else ret += word[i] + ' ';
   }
   return str;
}


function w_6_wid(title) {
   title = w_3_wid(title, 15);
   title = w_4_wid(title, 60);
   return title;
}

w_6_wid(str);
```

Comment: I have no clue what it does.. but I would highly recommend hiring a new programmer...

Comment: Why do you want to know? Why did your programmer gave this to you?

Comment: In the end, it does a lot of nothing since the return value from `w_6_wid()` is ignored.

Comment: Gotta love those function names!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`w_4_wid` appears to truncate a block of text to a maximum number of characters, without splitting words, and if the text is truncated to add '...' elipses at the end of the sentence.

`w_3_wid` seems to do something similar, imposing a maximum number of characters per word.

`w_6_wid` calls the above two functions in a chain, imposing both constraints on the input text.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the code is trying to take a sentence and then first truncate long words given a threshold, and then truncate the whole sentence (given another threshold), ending the sentence with "...".

Answer (score 1):

first: your programmer should read the book "Clean Code".

The idea of the function `w_3_wid` is -  for what ever reason - to trunkate words which are longer than 15 characters AND containing an html entity (like `&nbsp;`)

The second function (`w_4_wid`) truncates the string at word boundaries.

The last one (`w_6_wid`) combines both functions.

To test these code you can append something like this:

```
alert(w_6_wid('Lorem ipsum abcdefghijklmnopqu abcdefghijklm&bnsp;nopqu'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`w_4_wid` looks like it tries to truncate a sentence to a maximum width of the second parameter(60).

Comment: Thanks scheffield - hadn't spotted that.  Amended my answer to avoid further confusion.